# Call function with dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I have the following function that is storing values in an object with a dynamic id mentioned below.

```
function getCoordinates(id, index) {
  scroll_value_Y = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollTop;
  scroll_value_X = document.getElementById("svg_editor").scrollLeft;
  offset_x = 298;
  offset_y = 102;
  var p = $('#' + id);
  var offset = p.offset();
  var left = Math.round(offset.left - offset_x + scroll_value_X);
  var top = offset.top - offset_y + scroll_value_Y;
  var o = {
    ['' + a1]: {
      x: left,
      y: top
    }
  };
}
```

I want to access the object's content in another function call which is as follows :

```
drawAggregate(o.a1.x,o.a1.y,o.a2.x,o.a2.y);
```

Here the variables `a1`, `a2` store id of elements that I am using as index to store X,Y coordinates in the object. How can I use `a1` and `a2` in a way that their value is used as index in the function call.

Comment: How is a1 supposed to be defined in getCoordinates?

Comment: @Matt just declared it as global variable

Comment: If it is a string (assuming a1 === 'a1' here), it should probably be `var o = { a1: { x: left, y: top } }`.    If thats the case, I don't know what you mean by indexing.